# Not enough attention to answers on question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question includes more than one problem.

So my first problem is, many times I have seen that people (including myself) put enormous effort into answering some questions, but the question author just ignores it, and I don’t know why. Maybe they think that since their work is done they don’t need to thank the author of the answer or something else.

So the solution to this problem, according to me, should be that some trusted community members, or maybe all members, could vote to choose an answer as correct if the question author doesn’t.

My second problem is, there are multiple answers to a question and the answer authors spend a lot of their time in making them. The problem is only one of many answers gets to be chosen as the correct one and gets voted on. But there are multiple other answers which answer the question using other code. But they don’t get any attention. Even when I search for an answer on Stack Overflow, I just see the first answer (unless it doesn’t answer me) and vote upon it and then exit the question. I think the other answers also should get some attention.

So, according to me, the answer to this problem should be that a mechanism should be implemented where we can choose multiple correct answers to the question and they should appear randomly on top whenever the question page is loaded.

So what do you guys think about these problems and their solutions according to me?

Comment: *"I just see the first answer and vote upon it and then close the question"* Don't you feel you are part of the problem them..? If the problem is that other answers aren't being looked at, why are you, yourself, not doing looking at them?

Comment: You’re putting too much importance on accepting answers. All that means is it helped the questioner. If it’s a good answer, it’ll get upvoted by other users and that’s a much more important thing overall than acceptance. But I do appreciate it can be annoying when you spend a lot of time answering and the OP ignores it.

Comment: @Larnu and that’s why I mentioned this. We everyone do the same thing (almost everyone). And that’s why I want another type of mechanism implemented.

Comment: *"should be that a mechanism should be implemented where we can choose multiple correct answers"* This feature exists, it's called upvoting.

Comment: You may be a bit confused on the purpose of voting, and in particular the purpose of the OP's "accepting" an answer. The acceptance signifies that that one particular answer best answers the question for the OP, nothing more and nothing less. The OP, and all of us ,have the ability to up-vote any answer that we deem to be helpful and site-appropriate, and the two concepts are separate.

Comment: @user438383 And when do they get upvoted? When the users see it of course! But the way SO works now, it shows the accepted answer or sometimes the most upvoted answer (which is often the accepted one) which doesnt allow other answers to be seen.

Comment: @Larnu But me, I always check the accepted answer first for my problem.

Comment: Please also see this cross-meta-site duplicate [Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18312/162852)

Comment: @user438383 The answer which is shown at top is the most upvoted one, I know, but it’s most often the accepted answer.

Comment: Acceptance does not equal "correct"! This is a common misconception stemming from the ridiculous decision of SE to include that relic of **forums** in the system. A 2**Infinity iteration: accept mark means *only* that an answer "helped the OP the most".

Comment: And so what if another answer is above yours? If your answer is very strong and well-written, over time it will accumulate up-votes as site users find that it helps them with their coding problems.

Comment: @Archit maybe that’s the case, but it’s not causative. Maybe it’s better to see accepted as different to upvoting. The site functions on upvotes and the accepted answer is just a nice add on which tells you the OP liked your answer.

Comment: Posts get upvoted when *other users* find them helpful, @ArchitGargi. We are in the mess of accepted answers getting upvoted to hell and beyond *precisely* because, for years, SE had the accepted answer *pinned* to the top. Even *they* realised how harmful it is and unpinned it recently.

Comment: *"I always check the accepted answer first for my problem."* and again, you therefore aren't helping the problem.

Comment: @Larnu Tell me one thing, who has so much time when writing some code to check every answer on a question and acknowledge them!

Comment: @ArchitGargi When I search I will take the time to read several of the answers, often starting at the most upvoted. So to answer your question, I *do* take the time to read the answers. Unfortunately, I don't often have need to search, as I don't often work outside of the tags I am a (self proclaimed) SME.

Comment: The vibe I am getting from your question and comments, if I am honest, is "I want [my] answers that don't have upvotes to be upvoted. This should happen because people should read several of the answers and can vote on all the answers that helped them. I, however, don't want to spend the time to look at several answers when I have a problem, just give me answers quickly; I don't care about the quality." Your intent in the question, and your interaction in the comments come across as very contradictory or hypocritical.

Comment: @Larnu Pls larnu, my question says the solution to it is not forcing people to read the answers but to show them in random way! To be honest that comment is somewhat insulting.

Comment: *"the solution to it is not forcing people to read the answers"* So we should randomly give them the *worst* answer to read sometimes, and put the "best" answer on page 3? Yes, that sounds like a "wonderful" solution...

Comment: So that answer can only accrue more upvotes and the rest get lost to the void? The "best" answer (read most upvoted) is not always the *best* answer (read best). There are some terrible answers out there that are heavily upvoted.

Comment: *"To be honest that comment is somewhat insulting."* To confirm, the comment is in no way intended to be insulting. My point is purely to note that your comments and question seem to conflict. You've stated your answers aren't getting enough votes on them, due to not getting attention, but then state that you don't want to read more than one answer, and in fact only present one answer (in a deleted comment). The intention of your question, to get answers read, and your actions are opposites; if you won't read multiple answers, why should others?

Comment: [Here's a question that has one of my most-visited answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658734). It was accepted and is highest voted. It exactly answers the question as asked, but it's one of the stupidest ways C++ offers to read a file. Odds are good what the asker REALLY needed was the second answer. Odds are **very** good that the other visitors need the second answer.  Yet people kept upvoting it and probably using it, so I added a warning at the top of the question suggesting that they try the other answer first. And it's STILL getting the occasional upvote.

Comment: Why are you asking all these questions in the comments, on which your question is based, instead of researching them before you considered posting? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: "but the question author just ignores it, I don’t know why". I'll do you one better (or worse). Some delete the question after they get an answer. Hit & run tactics.

Comment: @Gimby Lol but I noticed SO doesn’t allow people to delete their question once people have answered upon it.

Comment: Related (unfair different levels of attention due to *timing*): [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)

Comment: @ArchitGargi there is a window of time where it is possible, namely when there is one answer and that answer has not been upvoted yet. So a student that is waiting for an answer and then quickly deletes it so a teacher cannot find it... it happens. Point is, not everyone is a saint.

Comment: Aside from the way the idea is presented in this question, the proposed change makes perfect sense. For a reliable A/B/C test controlling for factors other than an answer's usefulness (assuming this is one of SO's prioritized goals), suitable candidates would need to be presented in random order.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Finally someone who is agreeing

Comment: @ArchitGargi - With lots of *if*s and no concrete suggestion on how to select *suitable candidates*, not to mention that it might irritate many users [...].But other than that, I think the idea is worth considering

Comment: To Michael's point, I think this isn't a very researched or thought through proposal. If there are 3 answers at +1, +10, +100... Do we show the +1? The +10? And.... In theory, this doesn't solve the 'people don't read more than one answer' issue. It just dilutes the views on answers, and basically means that new users could be tripped in seeing the second best answer. Which feels VERY counter productive to Stack's goal :/

Comment: another part of your question was also covered before, by [Community accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418574/839601) and its multiple duplicates

Comment: @Patrice - counterintuitive as it sounds, this is a valid method for estimating the 'real' rank of different solutions. Any +1, +10, +100 answer would be considered the best answer with equal probability until we are more certain of how many upvotes they would get if presented at the top of the list. In practice, this would exploit a subset of users for the process, depriving them of a satisfying experience.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I agree, my proposal is that it shows random answer which have upvotes on the top until it’s absolutely certain which answer is best and put it on top.

Comment: @Michael and these 'exploited users' who come here to get the 'best' answer and then is shown "random answer number 5" are the ones we should think about in this instance, I think

Comment: @Patrice - perhaps opt-in for 'unbiased rank' sorting?

Comment: @Michael we have trouble with new users understanding 'green checkmark doesn't mean good answer'. I feel like this will end up making that even worse. No one will want the 'random rank'... Except maybe in the context of reviews?

Answer (score 17):

> the solution to this problem according to me should be that some trusted community members or maybe all members could vote to choose an answer as correct if the question author doesn’t.

We already have that. It's called upvoting. The purpose of upvotes is exactly that: to show which answer is correct.

It looks like you are misunderstanding the purpose of the answer accept feature. It's only meant to allow the question asker to give their seal of approval. It doesn't mean that the answer with the green checkmark is the correct solution or the best solution. It only means that the person who asked the question liked that solution more than others. The question asker doesn't have to use that feature. It's completely optional.

The best answer should be the one that has the highest score.

Comment: Pls read the discussion on the question.

Comment: @ArchitGargi What makes you think I haven't read it yet? If there's some crucial information in the comments under your post then it's your responsibility to add that information into the body of the post.

Comment: *"The best answer should be the one that has the highest score."* I honestly wish this were true though. Sometimes bounties should be taken into considering, and sometimes highly upvoted comments under the answer *warning* you about problems with the answer should not be ignored. The best way to find the "best" answer (read best) is to actually read several of the answers and related comments, and compliment with your own tests and other research.

Answer (score 17):

> Maybe they think that since their work is done they don’t need to thank the author of the answer or something else.

Guess what, that is because they literally don't need to. *No one* is required to be thankful for, to accept, or to upvote content just because it was posted in the answer box.

If you want answers to get attention, write *interesting* answers to *interesting* questions. They might be insightful, or surprising, or inspiring, but they aren't going to be interesting just for being there.

People *do* decide on good answers and questions *all the time*. Even when they do not vote, even when they do not even open a question, they do rate content. If you want people to care about your answers and to be thankful for them, ensure the answers actually deserve it.

Comment: In fact, thanking the answerer is discouraged on Stack Overflow. They are useless comments, and upvoting/accepting is there for you